# Latest News not showing articles in categories?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I tried to display some articles in the latest article news module but they only show up if they are uncategorized, if I putt them in a category the they don't show up. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. Global Configuration -> Articles -> Shared Options. Set the Category Order to: No Order.

Comment: Please accept this answer to mark it as solved

Answer (score 0):

Goto backend -> content -> Article manager -> Add new article now you can create a one article with your need category then Extension manager -> Module manager -> New -> Latest News -> you can set the need category in that category box.